# Azure SQL deployment task with AAD authentication

Tags: azure-deployment

This

[image]

suggests that it's possible to use AAD rather than SQL Server Authentication to do the deployment.
Is that true?

I turned on the managed identity in the Azure SQL Server but none of these three AAD options work. Do I need to do something else? What?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

To use Azure AD authentication, you need to set one Azure AD user as **Admin** of your SQL server like below:

[image]

Now, you can run one **Azure DevOps SQL Database Deployment** task by selecting `Active Directory -Password` authentication which is your Azure AD user credentials like below:

[image]

You can add your Azure subscription and Azure SQL details like below:

[image]

When you select add, your Azure SQL task is added in the YAML pipeline like below:

```yaml
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'SID subscription(01xxx365-f598-44d6-b4xd-e2b6xxxxa7)'
    AuthenticationType: 'aadAuthenticationPassword'
    ServerName: 'siliconserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'silicondb'
    aadSqlUsername: 'spuser@xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
    aadSqlPassword: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
    deployType: 'InlineSqlTask'
    SqlInline: |
            SELECT * FROM Products
    IpDetectionMethod: 'IPAddressRange'
    StartIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    EndIpAddress: '255.255.255.255'
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in SSMS, table is created in database like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure-pipelines-tasks/README.md at master · microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/README.md)